# How to search in SphinxQL by sql_attr_multi field

Tags: sphinx

This is my query to sphinxQL:

```
SELECT  option_id FROM items WHERE cat IN (10,11) GROUP BY option_id LIMIT 100000 OPTION max_matches=100000
```

cat is sql_attr_multi field, this query not return to me correct result. Anybody knows how to search by fields by this sphinx attribute?

Answer (score 0):

That query looks for items where `cat` attribute contains either 10 **OR** 11, is that what you trying to do?

If its not, would help to know what you *are* trying to query!

Comment: Right, but it's doesn't work correct, if I shall set this as sql_attr_uint then it works but for sql_attr_multi not.

Comment: You will need to provide more detail if want help diagnosing. Eg how do you build your MVA?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem.

When I pass array to IN condition for MVA attribute I have no result, however there is several ones in index.
When I debug condition (attribute array(10, 11) in you case) I see that array values is string integer instead.

```
array(
  0 => "10",
  1 => "11"
)
```

For every single value in condition uses quoteArr() function
https://github.com/FoolCode/SphinxQL-Query-Builder/blob/master/src/SphinxQL.php#L518
wich escape value according with https://github.com/FoolCode/SphinxQL-Query-Builder/blob/master/src/Drivers/ConnectionBase.php#L95

The quote function use is_int() PHP internal function:

```
$a = "1";
var_dump(is_int($a)); // return bool(false)
```

It mean, thet instead

```
cat IN (10, 11)
```

you have

```
cat IN ("10", "11")
```

But sphinx can't filter MVA attribute by not integer (string) values no metter IN or OR WHERE notation you use.

```
[1064] index document : unsupported filter type 'string' on MVA column [ SELECT * FROM `document` WHERE MATCH('(some query)') AND `_category` = '5' LIMIT 0, 10]
```

You should use strict value type:

```
foreach ($category as &$item) {
    $item = (int)$item;
} unset($item);
```

I am not sure that it is your incindent. Unfortunately, there isn't enough data to say it for sure in this case.